# python-ldap unable to do any basic search queries on open server

Tags: python, ldap, ldap-query, python-ldap

I have been trying to do some basic search queries, but I am unable to connect to an open LDAP server regardless. I tried a couple of servers, and none of them worked. I used Apache Directory Studio to make sure that the keyword was there but it did not work either way. I tried a variety of different code from different sources. 
This was the first one I used 
:
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6988

```
import ldap


keyword = "boyle"
def main():
    server = "ldap.forumsys.com"
    username = "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com"
    password = "password"

    try:
        l = ldap.open(server)
        l.simple_bind_s(username,password)
        print "Bound to server . . . "
        l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
        print "Searching . . ."
        mysearch (l,keyword)

    except ldap.LDAPError:
        print "Couldnt connect"

def mysearch(l, keyword):

    base = ""
    scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
    filter = "cn=" + "*" + keyword + "*"

    retrieve_attributes = None

    count = 0
    result_set = []
    timeout = 0
    try:
        result_id = l.search(base, scope, filter, retrieve_attributes)

        while l != 1:
            result_id = l.search(base, scope,filter, retrieve_attributes)
            result_type, result_data = l.result(result_id, timeout)
            if result_data == []:
                break
            else:
                if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
                    result_set.append(result_data)

        if len (result_set = 0):
            print "No Results"

        for i in range (len(result_set)):
            for entry in result_set[i]:
                try:
                    name = entry[1]['cn'][0]
                    mail = entry[1]['mail'][0]
                    #phone = entry[1]['telephonenumber'][0]
                    #desc = entry[1]['description'][0]
                    count = count + 1
                    print name + mail
                except:
                    pass
    except ldap.LDAPError, error_message:
        print error_message

main()
```

Every time I ran this program, I received an error 
{'desc': u"No such object"}

I also tried this

```
import ldap

try:

  l = ldap.open("ldap.example.com")


except ldap.LDAPError, e:
  print e


base_dn = "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com"

search_scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
retrieve_attributes = None
search_filter = "uid=myuid"

try:
  l_search = l.search(base_dn, search_scope, search_filter, retrieve_attributes)
  result_status, result_data = l.result(l_search, 0)
  print result_data
except ldap.LDAPError, e:
  print e
```

The error on this one was 
{'desc': u"Can't contact LDAP server"}

I spent about 5 hours trying to figure this out. I would really appreciate it if you guys could give me some advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several bogus things in there.

I will only comment your first code sample because it can be used by anyone with that [public LDAP server](https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/).

> l = ldap.open(server)

Function ldap.open() is deprecated since many years. You should use function [ldap.initialize()](https://python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html#ldap.initialize) with LDAP URI as argument instead like this:

```
l = ldap.initialize("ldap://ldap.forumsys.com")
```

> l_search = l.search(..)

This is the asynchronous method which just returns a message ID (int) of the underlying OpenLDAP C API (libldap). It's needed if you want to retrieve extended controls returned by the LDAP server along with search results. Is that what you want?

As a beginner you probably want to use the simpler method [LDAPObject.search_s()](https://python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html#ldap.LDAPObject.search_s) which immediately returns a list of (DN, entry) 2-tuples.

See also: [python-ldap -- Sending LDAP requests](https://python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html#sending-ldap-requests)

> while l != 1

This does not make sense at all because *l* is your *LDAPObject* instance (LDAP connection object). Note that *LDAPObject.search()* would raise an exception if it gets an Integer error code from OpenLDAP's *libldap*. No need to do C-style error checks at this level.

> filter = "cn=" + "*" + keyword + "*"

If *keyword* can be arbitrary input this is a prone to [LDAP injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/LDAP_injection). Don't do that.

For adding arbitrary input into a LDAP filter use function [ldap.filter.escape_filter_chars()](https://python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap-filter.html#ldap.filter.escape_filter_chars) to properly escape special characters. Also avoid using variable name *filter* because it's the name of a built-in Python function and properly enclose the filter in parentheses.

Better example:

```
ldap_filter = "(cn=*%s*)" % (ldap.filter.escape_filter_chars(keyword))
```

> base = ""

The correct search base you have to use is:

base = "dc=example,dc=com"

Otherwise [ldap.NO_SUCH_OBJECT](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html#ldap.NO_SUCH_OBJECT) is raised.

So here's a complete example:

```
import pprint

import ldap
from ldap.filter import escape_filter_chars

BINDDN = "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com"
BINDPW = "password"
KEYWORD = "boyle"

ldap_conn = ldap.initialize("ldap://ldap.forumsys.com")
ldap_conn.simple_bind_s(BINDDN, BINDPW)

ldap_filter = "(cn=*%s*)" % (ldap.filter.escape_filter_chars(KEYWORD))

ldap_results = ldap_conn.search_s(
    "dc=example,dc=com",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    ldap_filter,
)

pprint.pprint(ldap_results)
```